# Knockout JS - Modifying properties of items in observableArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to update the umber shown in red to reflect the positions of each item in an observableArray when one item has been repositioned. You can see my current code here: http://jsfiddle.net/BV87N/

It's not quite behaving the way I would expect it to. I have a feeling it's because the items and their properties inside of the array are not observable themselves.

But I'm not quite sure how to get this to work.

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.afterMove = function () {
    self.adjustOrder();
};

self.adjustOrder = function () {
    for (var i = 0, j = self.items().length; i < j; i++) {
        self.items()[i].sortOrder = i;
    };
};
```

Comment: Sounds like a good initial hypothesis. Test it by making the sortOrder observable and then *updating* the same observable. Although, it might make more sense to make `sortOrder` a computed observable dependent upon the `items` observable array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very explicitly stated in the documentation of [observable Arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

> **Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array,
>   not the state of those objects**
>
> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of
>   that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can
>   make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an
>   independent choice.

So you need to make your `sortOrder` properties `ko.observable()` (there is a plugin called [Knockout Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which could help in that) and then change your `adjustOrder` to

```
self.adjustOrder = function () {
    for (var i = 0, j = self.items().length; i < j; i++) {
        self.items()[i].sortOrder(i);
    };
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCe4w/).

SideNote: But in your case you don't really need any on your `sortOrder` properties because the order of the items in the `items` is the sort order. So in your bindings you can use just `$index` ([binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) property) instead of `sortOrder`.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gERXD/).

Comment: Thanks nemesv, but my real issue arises from the fact that in my real app, the data being given to the observable array is a JSON array from an ajax call. So I can't specify the sortOrder property to be observable as in your first Demo. This is what the Mapping plugin can be used for?

Comment: Yes, this is the goal of the Mapping plugin to support these use cases. In your sample you just need to replace `ko.observableArray` with `ko.mapping.fromJS` and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/GDDxK/. Because the `ko.mapping.fromJS` turns a regular JavaScript array into an observable array and goes through each item and turns the properties into `ko.obserable` objects.